# How can I skip a term with List.Map in OCAML?

Tags: ocaml

Suppose I have some code like this:

```
List.map (fun e -> if (e <> 1) then e + 1 else (*add nothing to the list*))
```

Is there a way to do this?  If so, how?

I want to both manipulate the item if it matches some criteria and ignore it if it does not.  Thus List.filter wouldn't seem to be the solution.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

SML has a function mapPartial which does exactly this. Sadly this function does not exist in OCaml. However you can easily define it yourself like this:

```
let map_partial f xs =
  let prepend_option x xs = match x with
  | None -> xs
  | Some x -> x :: xs in
  List.rev (List.fold_left (fun acc x -> prepend_option (f x) acc) [] xs)
```

Usage:

```
map_partial (fun x -> if x <> 1 then Some (x+1) else None) [0;1;2;3]
```

will return `[1;3;4]`.

Or you can use [`filter_map` from extlib](http://ocaml-extlib.googlecode.com/svn/doc/apiref/ExtList.List.html#VALfilter_map) as ygrek pointed out.

Answer (score 7):

Both [Batteries](http://batteries.forge.ocamlcore.org) and [Extlib](http://ocaml-extlib.googlecode.com/svn/doc/apiref/index.html) provide an equivalent of `mapPartial`: their extended `List` module sprovide a `filter_map` function of the type `('a -> 'b option) -> 'a list -> 'b list`, allowing the map function to select items as well.

Answer (score 5):

Another solution would be to use directly a `foldl` :

```
let f e l = if (e <> 1) 
            then (e + 1)::l 
            else l
in List.fold_left f [] list
```

But my preference is `filter_map` as Michael Ekstrand provided

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively you can filter your list then apply the map on the resulted list as follows :

```
let map_bis predicate map_function lst =
    List.map map_function (List.filter predicate lst);;

# val map_bis : ('a -> bool) -> ('a -> 'b) -> 'a list -> 'b list = <fun>
```

Usage :

```
# map_bis (fun e -> e<>1) (fun e -> e+1) [0;1;2;3];;
- : int list = [1; 3; 4]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also map values to singleton lists if you want to keep them or empty lists if you don't, and then concat the results.

```
List.concat (List.map (fun e -> if (e <> 1) then [e + 1] else []) my_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

use

```ml
let rec process = function
  | 1 :: t -> process t
  | h :: t -> (h + 1) :: (process t)
  | []     -> []
```

or tail recursive

```ml
let process = 
  let rec f acc = function
    | 1 :: t -> f acc t
    | h :: t -> f ((h + 1) :: acc) t
    | []     -> List.rev acc in
  f []
```

or with a composition of standard functions

```
let process l = 
  l |> List.filter ((<>)1)
    |> List.map ((+)1)
```

Answer (score 1):

The OCaml standard library has had [`List.filter_map`](https://ocaml.org/api/List.html#VALfilter_map) since 4.08. This can therefore now be written as:

```
List.filter_map (fun e -> if e <> 1 then Some (e + 1) else None)
```